# Having unit and integration tests in one project

Tags: .net, tfs, mstest

If I want to combine unit and integration tests in a single test project. How do I make sure that I'll be able run only unt tests subset during CI automated builds?

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?  And what are you using for CI?

Comment: @cadrell0, TFS 2012 for CI and MSTest for unit testing

Answer (score 4):

You could annotate each test [TestCategory("Unit")] or [TestCategory("Integration")].
It would be nice to compile the project to two dlls but I don't know a way.

Comment: How do you then make CI build (in TFS 2012) run only tests which are not marked with the "Integration" category?

Comment: I found this link.  I don't use TFS, so I'm not sure if it will help.  http://www.edsquared.com/2009/09/25/Test+Categories+And+Running+A+Subset+Of+Tests+In+Team+Foundation+Server+2010.aspx

Comment: Not sure of TFS specifics but normally CI server should have a configuration step to execute command line MSTest.exe/Nunit.exe. If you find this configuration, then just add command line parameter something like "MSTest.exe /category Integration yourtest.dll".   (sorry I Answered instead of Comment because of not enough reputation points!)

Comment: More on MSTest.exe as the test runner http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx